# package ‘ggplot2’ x.x.x is loaded, but > x.x.x is required by ‘plotly’

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, install.packages

I am trying to use 'plotly' package in R to build graphs, but I am getting the following error:

```
package ‘ggplot2’ 2.1.0 is loaded, but > 2.1.0 is required by ‘plotly’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘plotly’ was built under R version 3.2.5
```

I have tried installing 'ggplot2' and 'plotly' again and again, but the error still remains the same.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Make sure you have the current version of ggplot2 (which is 2.2.0).  The message about what version of R it was built under is a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating everything. Use the `installr` package like so:

```
install.packages("installr")

library(installr)
updateR()
```

Then be sure that you update the packages when prompted to do so.

Comment: When tried to install "installr" I got the following error message: 
"package ‘installr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)"

Comment: Are you trying it in RGUI or RStudio? Try it outside of RStudio and see what happens.

Comment: I could not install "installr" so I updated the ggplot2 library to work around the problem, 
Thank you

Comment: You should update R though as well. The version you are running is more than 1 year old.